# Overview Panel not displaying layers in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, map-overviews

I'm learning about the QGIS GUI. I've loaded a sample Alaska raster with the vector lakes layer, and activate the overview panel. However, the layers are not displaying within the panel. The extent rectangle is displayed, and I am able to use it to change the extent as normal.

Is there any way to fix the overview panel so  it displays the layers as expected?

Comment: What were you expecting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For each layer that you want shown in the Overview panel do either of the following:

- Right click on the layer in the Layers panel and select "Show in Overview"
- Left click on the layer in the Layers panel and select "Add to Overview" from the Layer menu.

To show all layers in the Overview panel select "Add all to Overview" from the Layer menu.